# Can we use C++/CX events and COM (Component Object Model) together?

Tags: events, com, c++-cx

I write a graphics engine based on COM. Also I really love C#-style events and I plan add to API something like "events". As far as I know in COM events can be implemented with the so called "connection points" but it looks awful! Also in C++/CX we have key word "event" and the same normal way to use events as in C#. But I did not find any examples of using C++/CX in COM. Is it possible?

Comment: c++-cx is essentially COM based so (1) using events there is not the same as using events in C# (2) by using c++-cx you are already using COM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can combine the two but depending on how your customers use your engine, they might not like it; using WinRT events from C is not pretty.

[C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/index) would be a better choice than C++/CX now that it's available; it is smaller, faster, and 100% standards-compliant. You will still need to create Windows Metadata (WinMDs) by writing IDL though.